# How to make a button click event to call dojo function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, function, dojo

I have a some javascript need some help from the lovely community. I am doing some thing about Jquery and DOJO.

I have two existing applications.

Application one use a lots of dojo/spring UI decoration/Validation (spring 3.1.1). And other one is pure html application.

What I am doing now? I am trying to put two projects together by using Jquery/Ajax call from HTML project talk to my spring project to get some business logic page generated from JSP, and inject the JSP page into particular HTML page div (Content div). I had did quite lots work on this work, and I found Jquery 1.9.1 doing well in Ajax and JSP injection. But when I try to call my existing JSP page's Spring/DOJO decoration/validation function, I found there is significant conflict between Jquery and DOJO, they can't live together at all.

And from then, I had to give up Jquery as I had heavily used Spring/DOJO. I found DOJO is not same with Jquery in javascript function call.

For example, I can very easy to fire a Jquery function from a button click event as:

javascript as:

```
function doSignout() {
console.log("dosignout function called.");
$.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'doSignout',
    query: ({name : "me"}),
       success: function(data){
          if (data=="login required."){
            doAjax();
           }
       }
     });
}
```

HTML as:

```
<input value="Sign out" name="Sign out" id="Sign out" class="submit" type="submit" onClick="doSignout()" />
```

But I found out, there is no way to do the same in dojo.

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Cidy from Australia

Answer (score 0):

have you tried instead of

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'doSignout',
    query: ({name : "me"}),
       success: function(data){
          if (data=="login required."){
            doAjax();
         }
       }
});
```

this would be the dojo equivalent

```
dojo.xhrPost({
    url:'doSignout',
    content: {key1:"value1",key2:{key3:"value2"}},
    load:function(data){
        if (data=="login required."){
            doAjax();
        }
    }
});
```

check the following links from the dojo documentation:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/xhrPost.html#dojo-xhrpost

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/xhrGet.html#dojo-xhrget

the tutorials for listening for events using dojo/on

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/events/

and dojo.connect:

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/events/

you only need the "DOM Events" part

Comment: This part is working for me, I tried. My problem is I can't call dojo function by click a button to fire a dojo function as Jquery can do it. I mean seems dojo function is not listen to a DOM element (button) click event. Any idea?

Comment: depending on what version of dojo you are using, you could try either "dojo.connect" or "dojo/on" to listen to dom events. but that is strage because the way you call the doSignout() function is not related to either jQuery or dojo that is the browser default. unles you are doing a jQuery.click and not showing it